# accessing mysql columns as arrays

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have two tables one for posts and another one for comments ,
**posts table**

| post_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 |
| 2 | row2 |
| 3 | row3 |

**comments**

| post_id | Another header | user id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | comment | 2 |
| 1 | comment 2 | 3 |

i want to read the code as follows:

post:{
id:1,
comments:[{text:"My comment",userId:3},
}

Comment: You want to read the code as follows `post:{ id:1, comments:[{text:"My comment",userId:3}, }` where??? on mysql console?

Comment: I am using nodejs so I want it to return it as an object or as an array objects

Comment: Read the documentation for [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and [JSON_OBJECTAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg).

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = require('mysql2'); // async/await works only in mysql2 

// I am supposing your comments table has post_id, another_header and user_id columns

app.get('/comments', async (req, res) => {
   const comments = await db.query('Select * from comments');
   let arrayOfObjects = [];
   comments.forEach(elem => {
      arrayOfObjects.push({
         id: elem.post_id,
         comments: elem.another_header,
         user_id: elem.user_id
      });
   })
   console.log(arrayOfObjects);
});
```

Comment: This will return an array of comment objects ,I want a post or array of posts with the comments being an array inside a post